# Running DocumentationTool on sources from OpenJDK 11

Tags: java, clojure, javadoc

I am trying to run `DocumentationTool` on sources from OpenJDK 11.

The output looks like this:

```
Constructing Javadoc information...
/Users/Borkdude/git/openjdk-jdk11/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/IllegalStateException.java:26: error: package exists in another module: java.base
package java.lang;
```

and this repeats about a 100 times.

The code I have looks like this in Clojure:

```clj
(import '[javax.tools ToolProvider])
(let [dt (ToolProvider/getSystemDocumentationTool)
        fm (.getStandardFileManager dt nil nil nil)
        files (.getJavaFileObjectsFromFiles
               fm
               (filter #(str/ends-with? (.getPath %) ".java")
                       (file-seq (io/file "/Users/Borkdude/git/openjdk-jdk11/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang"))))
        task (.getTask dt nil fm nil nil nil files)]
    (.call task))
```

How do I get rid of the error:

```
error: package exists in another module: java.base
package java.lang;
```

?

Comment: I assume this usage of the javadoc doesn't work with JDK 9 or 10 either, I just tried `ToolProvider.getSystemDocumentationTool().run(System.in, System.out, System.err, "--patch-module", "java.base=src/java.base/share/classes", "-d", "docs", "java.lang")` which I think is close to what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can either compile the entire module, or you need to "patch" the module. Here's an example of each, assuming you unzip `src.zip` to `/tmp`.

To compile the entire module:

```clj
(import '[javax.tools ToolProvider])
(require '[clojure.string :as str])

(let [dt (ToolProvider/getSystemDocumentationTool)
      fm (.getStandardFileManager dt nil nil nil)
      files (.getJavaFileObjectsFromFiles
             fm
             (filter #(str/ends-with? (.getPath %) ".java")
                     (file-seq (io/file "/tmp/src/java.base/"))))
      task (.getTask dt nil fm nil nil nil files)]
  (.call task))
```

To patch the module (i.e. compile only certain sources):

```clj
(let [dt (ToolProvider/getSystemDocumentationTool)
      fm (.getStandardFileManager dt nil nil nil)
      files (.getJavaFileObjectsFromFiles
             fm
             (filter #(str/ends-with? (.getPath %) ".java")
                     (file-seq (io/file "/tmp/src/java.base/java/lang"))))
      opts ["--patch-module" "java.base=/tmp/src"]
      task (.getTask dt nil fm nil nil opts files)]
  (.call task))
```